# Shell script to check file age and rename it

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm new in Linux and currently, I want to create a shell script to check any files that have N days old in a specified directory and rename it.
Example:

```
/home/foo/oldfile.txt
2019-01-01
```

into

```
/home/foo/oldfile.txt.old
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know how to do any part of this?  Do you know how to find files that are *N* days old?  Do you know how to rename files?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename any file more than N days old (N=30 in this example), try:

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "$1.old"' MV {} \;
```

The above search recursively under the current directory.  If you don't want it to descend into subdirectories, use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +3 -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "$1.old"' MV {} \;
```

For safety, you might want to try this command first and, if you like the results, remove the `echo`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +3 -exec sh -c 'echo mv -i "$1" "$1.old"' MV {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `find .`

  This starts a `find` command in the current directory, `.`.
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` to look only for regular files.
- `-mtime +30`

  This tells `find` to look only for files older than 30 days.  Replace `30` with whatever number you want.

  Note that,  because `find` has a peculiar way of rounding off the age of file, the exact cutoff for "more than 30 days old" may not be what you expect.  See `man find` for details.
- `-exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "$1.old"' MV {} \;`

  This tells `find` to run a `mv` command on every file found.  The `-i` option tells `mv` to ask interactively before overwriting an existing file.  There are variety of such options.  See `man mv` for details.

#### GNU find or similar

Some version of `find`, such as GNU `find`, make the use of `sh` in the above unnecessary (hat tip: [rush](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13003/rush)):

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv -i {} {}.old \;
```

This is not required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and thus may not be portable.

Comment: You don't need `sh -c` in exec. Find is able to use multiple `{}` in `-exec` statement with `\;`. Like this: `find . -exec mv {} {}.old \;`

Comment: @rush Very good suggestion.  Thank you.  I just added that to the answer along with a note that that behavior is not required by POSIX: _"If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change."_